# Why method "prepopulated_fields" doesn't work after saving object in Django admin?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-admin, slug

I have described a model where a slug field fills in values from another field automatically, but after saving the object, the slug stops working. I would like the slug field to work as expected every time the object is saved.

**models.py**:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

**admin.py:**

```py
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_as = True
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

The documentation says that this is done on purpose. I would be glad if someone could share their experience on solving this problem.

Comment: Normally slugs should *not* be renamed, since [*Cool URIs do not change*](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).

Comment: I know, but is there a way to avoid this rule?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.utils.text import slugify
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: No :( unfortunately this will not help solve the problem, because this construction only works if the field was initially empty.

Answer (score 0):

[The doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) says below so `prepopulated_fields` doesn't work after adding an object:

> Prepopulated fields aren’t modified by JavaScript after a value has
> been saved. It’s usually undesired that slugs change (which would
> cause an object’s URL to change if the slug is used in it).

So instead of using `prepopulated_fields`, you should override [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) as shown below to save `name` as `slug` every time you add and change an object:

```py
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```